# swipe menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to have a menu on the right and one on the left with jquery mobile.
With the help of this ([tutorial](https://codepen.io/fredddie/pen/gPKeEd)) I try to make a menu on the left and another menu on the right

I came to this result

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // only small screens
  if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
    // show menu on swipe to right
    $(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#menu').animate({
        left: '0'
      });
    });  // hide menu on swipe to left
    $(document).on('swipeleft', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#menu').animate({
        left: '-100%'
      });
    });
    // show menu on swipe to left
    $(document).on('swipeleft', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#menu2').animate({
        right: '0'
      });
    });  // hide menu on swipe to right
    $(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#menu2').animate({
        right: '-100%'
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #E64A4A;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  color: #fff;
}

#menu2 {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
</ul>
<ul id="menu2">
  <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
</ul>
<h1>Swipe to &lt;&lt; or &gt;&gt;</h1>
```

The problem is that there is no middle point without a menu
Why there is no middle ground without menus? where I went wrong?

Comment: See the JQM documentation: [The demo page has two menus, one at each side. Both can be opened with swipe](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-swipe-open/)

Answer (score 3):

First separate your logic by swipe, not menu.

Second, you will need to close the existing menu, if already opened, before opening a new one. This is you desired state.

I created a few jQuery plugins below to simplify the logic and improve readability.

**Update:** I simplified and verified the logic by storing a property to determine which side the screen the menu is on.

```js
(function() {
  $.swipeMenu = function(selector, options) {
    let $self = $(selector);
    $self.attr('data-direction', options.direction); // attribute
    $self.menuDirection = options.direction; // in-memory jQuery property
    return $self;
  };
  $.fn.openMenu = function() {
    this.animate({ [this.menuDirection] : 0 });
  };
  $.fn.closeMenu = function() {
    this.animate({ [this.menuDirection] : '-100%' });
  };
  $.fn.isMenuOpened = function() {
    return parseInt(this.css(this.menuDirection), 10) === 0;
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  const $leftMenu  = $.swipeMenu('#menu-1', { direction : 'left' });
  const $rightMenu = $.swipeMenu('#menu-2', { direction : 'right' });
  if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
    $(document).on('swipeleft', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($leftMenu.isMenuOpened()) {
        $leftMenu.closeMenu();
      } else {
        $rightMenu.openMenu();
      }
    });
    $(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($rightMenu.isMenuOpened()) {
        $rightMenu.closeMenu();
      } else {
        $leftMenu.openMenu();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#menu-1 {
  background-color: #E64A4A;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  color: #fff;
}

#menu-2 {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-1">
  <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
  <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu-2">
  <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
  <li><a href="#">Bam</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Pow</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Zip</a></li>
</ul>
<h1>Swipe to &lt;&lt; or &gt;&gt;</h1>
```

---

### Improved jQuery plugin

The next step would be to add the ability to link menus to each other and add the event listeners inside the plugin.

```js
/**
 * @plugin: jquery.swipe-menu.js
 */
(function($, window, undefined) {
  const defaults = { direction: 'left' };
  const methods = {
    init: function(options) {
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      return this
        .addClass('swipe-menu')
        .attr('data-direction', options.direction)
        .data('direction', options.direction)
        .css({
          [options.direction] : '-100%',
          // The default styles below could be defined in a stylesheet
          // e.g. jquery.swipe-menu.css
          position : 'fixed',
          top : 0,
          width : '80%',
          height : '100vh'
        });
    },
    open: function() {
      return this.animate({ [this.data('direction')]: 0 });
    },
    close: function() {
      return this.animate({ [this.data('direction')]: '-100%' });
    },
    isOpen: function() {
      return parseInt(this.css(this.data('direction')), 10) === 0;
    }
  };
  $.fn.swipeMenu = function(methodOrOptions) {
    if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
      return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.swipe-menu');
    }
  };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  const $leftMenu = $('#menu-1').swipeMenu();
  const $rightMenu = $('#menu-2').swipeMenu({ direction: 'right' });
  if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
    $(document).on('swipeleft', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($leftMenu.swipeMenu('isOpen')) {
        $leftMenu.swipeMenu('close');
      } else {
        $rightMenu.swipeMenu('open');
      }
    });
    $(document).on('swiperight', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if ($rightMenu.swipeMenu('isOpen')) {
        $rightMenu.swipeMenu('close');
      } else {
        $leftMenu.swipeMenu('open');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu-1 {
  background-color: #E64A4A;
  color: #fff;
}

#menu-2 {
  background-color: #4AE64A;
  color: #fff;
}

.unselectable {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
.ui-mobile-viewport, .ui-page { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.ui-loader { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="unselectable">Swipe to &lt;&lt; or &gt;&gt;</h1>
<div id="menu-1">
  <ul>
    <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-2">
  <ul>
    <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
    <li><a href="#">Bam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Zip</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

### Nearly complete jQuery plugin

The menus are now linked to each other and the event handler are inside the plugin. So the only logic the page is responsible for now is to establish the menus by initializing and linking them.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-1').swipeMenu({ link : '#menu-2' });
  $('#menu-2').swipeMenu({ direction: 'right', link : '#menu-1' });
});
```

```js
/**
 * @plugin: jquery.swipe-menu.js
 */
(function($, window, undefined) {
  const defaults = { direction: 'left', link : null };
  const methods = {
    init: function(options) {
      options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      attachSwipeEventHandlers(this);
      return this
        .addClass('swipe-menu')
        .attr('data-direction', options.direction)
        .data('direction', options.direction)
        .data('link', options.link)
        .css({
          [options.direction] : '-100%',
        })
    },
    open: function() {
      return this.animate({ [this.data('direction')]: 0 });
    },
    close: function() {
      return this.animate({ [this.data('direction')]: '-100%' });
    },
    isOpen: function() {
      return parseInt(this.css(this.data('direction')), 10) === 0;
    },
    link: function(link) {
      return this.data('link', link);
    },
    unlink: function() {
      return this.removeData('link');
    },
    linkedMenu : function() {
      return this.data('link') ? $(this.data('link')) : null;
    },
  };
  $.fn.swipeMenu = function(methodOrOptions) {
    if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
      return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.swipe-menu');
    }
  };
  function handleOpen($menu, $linkedMenu) {
    if (!$menu.swipeMenu('isOpen')) {
      if ($linkedMenu == null || !$linkedMenu.swipeMenu('isOpen')) {
        $menu.swipeMenu('open');
      }
    }
  }
  function handleClose($menu, $linkedMenu) {
    if ($menu.swipeMenu('isOpen')) {
      $menu.swipeMenu('close');
    }
  }
  function handleSwipe($menu, action) {
    let $linkedMenu = $menu.swipeMenu('linkedMenu');
    let menuDirection = $menu.data('direction');
    let linkedMenuDirection = $linkedMenu ? $linkedMenu.data('direction') : null;
    let reverse = menuDirection !== defaults.direction;
    switch (action) {
      case 'left' :
        reverse ? handleOpen($menu, $linkedMenu) : handleClose($menu, $linkedMenu);
        break;
      case 'right' :
        reverse ? handleClose($menu, $linkedMenu) : handleOpen($menu, $linkedMenu);
        break;
    }
  }
  function attachSwipeEventHandlers($menu) {
    $(document).on({
      'swipeleft' : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleSwipe($menu, 'left');
      },
      'swiperight' : function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        handleSwipe($menu, 'right');
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-1').swipeMenu({ link : '#menu-2' });
  $('#menu-2').swipeMenu({ direction: 'right', link : '#menu-1' });
});
```

```css
/* jquery.swipe-menu.js */
.swipe-menu {
  position : fixed;
  top : 0;
  width : 80%;
  height : 100vh;
}

/* Other styles... */
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu-1 { background: #E64A4A; color: #fff; }
#menu-2 { background: #4AE64A; color: #fff; }

.unselectable {
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
}
.ui-mobile-viewport, .ui-page { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.ui-loader { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="unselectable">Swipe to &lt;&lt; or &gt;&gt;</h1>
<div id="menu-1">
  <ul>
    <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
    <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="menu-2">
  <ul>
    <!--   YOUR LINKS GOES HERE   -->
    <li><a href="#">Bam</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pow</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Zip</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a problem when browsing the menus appear without swipe. When I press f5, problem is gone https://ibb.co/vQBH5vt

Comment: @Valy In my last example, I wrapped the lists in divs and moved the id from the list to the wrapping div. Please re-evaluate the full example above.